# navigate within Vaadin view with @ViewScope

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm using Vaadin 8 in a Spring Boot application and have a view scoped View.
I'm using view scope because I want to have a new instance each time I navigate to the view, and more importantly I don't want the view (and its data) to remain in memory when the user has navigated away from the view.

However, I would like to be able to navigate to this view from within the view itself, with different parameters.  In that case I don't want the view instance to be recreated (and its data to be reloaded).  Is there a way to do that?  Maybe with a custom Spring scope?

Comment: I don't think Vaadin spring supports that because you define the scope at compile time using annotations but you want to change it at runtime. But you can just put your view creation code (or the code that is depending on your data) in a separate method and call it once you need to refresh.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich I want the URL to change as well, and preferably not have to manage it myself (that's kind of what Navigator is for).  Regarding Scope: you choose it scope at compile time, but it is created at runtime.  It would need to be something between `@UIScope` and `@ViewScope`: only create a new scope when navigating to a different view but not when navigating to the same view with different parameters.

Comment: It looks like you need view parameters, see https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-navigator.html#advanced.navigator.urifragment. Basically, you interpret the view parameters in your `enter` method of the view and adapt/refresh the components of the view. Does that fit to your problem?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich I'm using view parameters but I want to keep the view instance when I'm navigating to the same view as the previous one, with different parameters.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich so I want to have the URL updated + `enter()` called on the current view instance.  When not using Spring, you can control that.  With Spring integration, view instance creation is controlled using Spring scopes.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem now. Did you solve it?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich not really though I have a workaround, but have not implemented it yet: make the View ‘@UIScope‘ but listen for view changes and clear the data / reset the content when navigating away from the view.